# How to create module with own entities for ASP NET BOILERPLATE Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, module, aspnetboilerplate

I am implemeting module with required functionality. This module is used on application template which can be downloaded from aspnetboilerplate site. The goal is simple: create module that adds own entities to main db, implements services and so on. I am using https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/sample-blog-module as example. I remade it for Core 2.2, added some more entites. For now my module has 3 class libraries: **MyModule.Application** (services, API), **MyModule.Core** (domain), **MyModule.EntityFrameworkCore** (dbContext, Migrations). The problem I am facing with is creating migrations. As you can see on sample above, module has own migration files which contain only module entites. But I am getting all tables generated on migrations file for my module (abp entities too).

Could someone explain how to create module for aspnetboilerplate Core version?
The main questions I interested in are:

1. How to create migrations for module entites only?
2. How get migration files on **MyModule.EntityFrameworkCore** lib?
3. Have I to create StartUp project (executable) for migration generating? (I use MyModule.EntityFrameworkCore as StartUp project now, it references Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design)
4. How to pass connection string from main app to my module via IOptions? I mean that there should be one appsettings.json file and it is placed on main app. The MyModule.EntityFrameworkCore lib should not have own one.

It will be great to get answer as "step by step"

PS: Module zero is used too

Thanks

Comment: DB Migrations is a big topic, there is a lot to cover in this question. It might help to break it down into smaller, focused questions, with examples of code that you have written, and errors being caused etc

Comment: Hi @RobertPerry. Thanks for reply. I agree with you. I have discovered features of ef core 2.2 and yes, it is the big topic. I know what to do now.